# Why websocket.send() depends on alert?

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I use websockets and Glassfish. I call start() funcion on load page. When start function contains alert it sends the message to the server but when I don't put the alert it doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

java script

```
function start() {
   alert('a'); //this alert
   webSocket.send('start_server');
}

function onMessage(event) {
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML
    += event.data;
}
```

server side

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) 
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Message recieved");
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);

}   

@OnOpen
public void onOpen() {
    System.out.println("Client connected");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you initialize the web-socket on the client side?
The alert suspends execution until you click ok - so i guess your order of execution is wrong (initialize the websocket before *webSocket.send*)

You may send data after the *WebSocket#open* event happend.

`var connection = new WebSocket(...)
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping');
};`

Source: [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Comment: I initialize websocket in the beginning of javascript file. Where should I initialize it?